# Wordpress SQL Query - meta_value date saved as string issues in php file - works in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

```
$query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT post_id
FROM {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta t1
WHERE meta_key = 'expiry_date'
AND STR_TO_DATE(meta_value, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN NOW() AND NOW() + INTERVAL 6 MONTH
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM wp_postmeta t2
            WHERE t2.meta_key = 'customer_email'
            AND t2.meta_value = %s
            AND t2.post_id = t1.post_id)
GROUP BY post_id", 'test@hotmail.co.uk');

$result = $wpdb->get_results( $query, ARRAY_A );
```

$result returns empty because of this:

```
AND STR_TO_DATE(meta_value, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN NOW() AND NOW() + INTERVAL 6 MONTH
```

meta_value column saves the date as a string hence I need to use STR_TO_DATE.

This query FULLY WORKS when I run it in phpmyadmin but not in my php wordpress file.
It only works inside my php file when I remove the line of code above.

Comment: I'm going to guess it's because `prepare` is using `sprintf`-type syntax, and the qualifiers for the date format is similar to the placeholders for sprintf, and it's not processing it right. Especially since `%d` is used as a digit for sprintf. Try adding a slash before the formatting for the dates, `'\%Y-\%m-\%d'`

Comment: Actually, looking at the [sprintf documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php), a percent sign is escaped with itself. So try `'%%Y-%%m-%%d'`

Comment: The Query Monitor plugin is your friend. It shows you the actual SQL WordPress uses, after `->prepare()`.

Comment: And from the [Wordpress documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/), `Literal percentage signs (%) in the query string must be written as %%.`

Answer (score 1):

@anyber Using '%%Y-%%m-%%d' solved this issue. Thanks